# inner join datos repetidos (mysql)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Hola gente buenas tardes, tengo que tomar datos de varias tablas (relacionadas entre si), me trae los datos que necesito, pero los repite, le he dado varias vueltas y no veo en que inner estara la falla, mi query esta asi:

```
SELECT
c.idCita, pa.idPaciente, prof.idRegistro, c.fecha_cita,
prof.nombres, prof.ape_pat, prof.ape_mat,
pa.rut_paciente, pa.nombres_paciente, pa.ape_pat, pa.ape_mat, pa.fecha_nacimiento,
h.hora,
ba.numBox
FROM
paciente pa INNER JOIN cita c
ON pa.idPaciente = c.idPaciente,
horas_atencion ha INNER JOIN hora h
ON  ha.idHora = h.idHora,
boxes_atencion ba INNER JOIN horas_atencion sa
ON ba.idBox = sa.idBox,
profesional prof INNER JOIN horas_atencion h1
ON prof.idRegistro = h1.idRegistro
WHERE c.estado_cita= 'REGISTRADA';
```

Saludos a todos, agradezco su apoyo desde ya...

Comment: Tienes le modelo fisico o conceptual de las tablas?

Comment: @FranciscoAcevedo este es el modelo que me pasaron: https://ibb.co/c0XzJK

Comment: Eso es muy fácil de determinar, ve agregando los `INNER JOIN` uno por uno y detectarás rápidamente dónde está el problema, el cual puede deberse a un inner incorrecto, pero también a que los datos están guardados mal. Viendo la consulta, resulta muy extraño que tengas que repetir tres veces la tabla `horas_atencion`, quizá deberías empezar uniendo por medio de esa tabla.

Comment: @A.Cedano en horas_atencion es donde me confundo, porque tengo llaves en esa tabla, estoy sguro que de ahi viene la confusion

Comment: Prueba la consulta así: `SELECT
c.idCita, pa.idPaciente, prof.idRegistro, c.fecha_cita,
prof.nombres, prof.ape_pat, prof.ape_mat,
pa.rut_paciente, pa.nombres_paciente, pa.ape_pat, pa.ape_mat, pa.fecha_nacimiento,
h.hora,
ba.numBox
FROM horas_atencion ha
 INNER JOIN cita c ON c.idHoraAtencion=ha.idHoraAtencion
 INNER JOIN paciente pa ON c.idPaciente=pa.idPaciente
 INNER JOIN hora h ON  ha.idHora = h.idHora
 INNER JOIN boxes_atencion ba ON ba.idBox = ha.idBox
 INNER JOIN profesional prof  ON prof.idRegistro = ha.idRegistro
WHERE c.estado_cita= 'REGISTRADA';`

Comment: Para un futuro ten en cuenta siempre este criterio: cuando haces `JOIN` usa en primer lugar la tabla que más llaves foráneas tenga, y a continuación ve agregando cada tabla como quieras, sin repetir tablas a menos que haya un doble JOIN para una determinada tabla. En realidad el orden en que se hagan los `JOIN` no importa, lo que importa es hacerlos sin repetir tablas.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por la consulta, me funciono, ademas, agradezco el comentario para trabajar de forma mas facil con los join, lo tomare en consideración...

Comment: Me alegro de te te haya funcionado. Te recomiendo que vayas haciendo los `JOIN` de forma organizada, como muestra la consulta de mi comentario más arriba. De ese modo el código será mucho más claro. Saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado, puedes probar de la siguiente forma:

```
                SELECT
                c.idCita, 
                pa.idPaciente, 
                prof.idRegistro, 
                c.fecha_cita,
                prof.nombres, 
                prof.ape_pat, 
                prof.ape_mat,
                pa.rut_paciente, 
                pa.nombres_paciente, 
                pa.ape_pat, 
                pa.ape_mat, 
                pa.fecha_nacimiento,
                h.hora,
                ba.numBox

                FROM paciente pa
                INNER JOIN cita c              ON pa.idPaciente = c.idPaciente, 

                horas_atencion ha

                INNER JOIN hora h              ON h.idHora = ha.idHora

                INNER JOIN boxes_atencion ba   ON ba.idBox = ha.idBox

                INNER JOIN profesional prof    ON prof.idRegistro = ha.idRegistro

                WHERE c.estado_cita= 'REGISTRADA';
```

Comment: gracias estimado, me funciono...